# How to delete file with this name on linux: -]???????q

Tags: linux, filenames, rm, special-characters

Somehow a file named `-]???????q` got created on my terminal. I tried  rm -f "-]???????q"  (in double quotes), but it did not get deleted. (Error::  `rm: invalid option -- ]`).  How do I delete it?

Comment: I had similar problem, in my case the problem was with samba implementation, just try to ssh to server and then remove it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For example, with:

```
rm -- '-]???????q'
```

Where `--` means: "stop parsing options".

Comment: Indeed, I ran into a similar problem not even thinking about - being a switch. I swear I spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Many applications use `--`, guess it's a kind of de facto standard due to the `getopt` function.

Answer (score 14):

You can either use the file name with rm or the inode number with find like :

```
rm -- -]???????q
# or
  -> ls -i                                                                                                                         
47984689 blah.ui  47983771 __init__.py  
47983773 testpy.e4p  47985161 Ui_blah.py

  -> find -inum 47983773                                                                                                           
./testpy.e4p

  -> find -maxdepth 1 -inum 47983773 -exec rm -i '{}' \;
#or
  -> find -maxdepth 1 -inum 47983773 -delete
```

Comment: Add -maxdepth 1 otherwise find will iterate through all subdirectories: `find -maxdepth 1 -inum 47983773 -delete`

Comment: @FabianRitzmann good call, I added it.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Accessing file with invalid characters in its name by its iNode is the only correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm ./"-]???????q"
```

Double quotes prevent the shell from expanding interrogation marks. For example, if you had another file called **-]foobar.q**:

```
$ touch ./"-]???????q" ./-]foobar.q
$ echo ./-]???????q
./-]foobar.q ./-]???????q
```

Comment: Oh. I put the quotes, but was missing the `./`